# How to get AccessKey to work with DataTemplate in NavigationView

Tags: datatemplate, winui-3, navigationview, access-keys

I am using WinUI 3 and WindowsAppSDK. When I use a NavigationView and set AccessKey on the NavigationViewItem, it works ... until I also define the MenuItemTemplate. As soon as a DataTemplate is used for the MenuItemTemplate, the access keys stop working. Any thoughts on how to work around this?

Here is an example. Any thoughts?

```
  <NavigationView>
      <NavigationView.MenuItems>
          <NavigationViewItem AccessKey="N">Nibble</NavigationViewItem>
          <NavigationViewItem AccessKey="P">Pancake</NavigationViewItem>
      </NavigationView.MenuItems>
      <!-- uncomment this to break the access key functionality
      <NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:DataType="NavigationViewItem">
              <StackPanel>
                  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Icon}" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
      </NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
      -->
  </NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `AccessKey` doesn't work because the original menu items, `NavigationViewItems` that has `AccessKeys`, get wrapped with `NavigationViewItem`.

Instead, this code will be something similar to what you are trying to achive:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WinUI3App;

public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem(string text, Symbol icon, string accessKey)
    {
        Text = text;
        Icon = icon;
        AccessKey = accessKey;
    }

    public string Text { get; }

    public Symbol Icon { get; }

    public string AccessKey { get; }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems = new()
    {
        new MenuItem(text: "Nibble", icon: Symbol.Emoji, accessKey: "N"),
        new MenuItem(text: "Pancake", icon: Symbol.Emoji2, accessKey: "P"),
    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI3App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3App"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <NavigationView MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind MenuItems, Mode=OneWay}">
        <NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
                <NavigationViewItem AccessKey="{x:Bind AccessKey}">
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*">
                        <SymbolIcon
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Symbol="{x:Bind Icon, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <TextBlock
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Text="{x:Bind Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Grid>
                </NavigationViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
    </NavigationView>

</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Using a NavigationViewItem for the outer element of the DataTemplate worked.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this to spell out the answer in case anyone would like to see it in full:

```
<NavigationView>
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem AccessKey="N">
            Nibble
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItem AccessKey="P">
            Pancake
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="NavigationViewItem">
            <NavigationViewItem AccessKey="{Binding AccessKey}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Icon}" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </NavigationViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
</NavigationView>
```